# Optimized sql query is slower than not optimized one?

Tags: mysql, optimization, benchmarking

A fellow programmer showed me a query he created which looked like this:

```
SELECT a.row, b.row, c.row
FROM 
a LEFT JOIN
b ON (a.id = b.id) LEFT JOIN
c ON (c.otherid= b.otherid)
WHERE a.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT b.id bb 
INNER JOIN
c cc ON (bb.a_id = cc.a_id)
WHERE (bb.date BETWEEN '2018-08-04 00:00:00' AND '2018-08-06 23:59:59'))
GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY c.otherid DESC;
```

So I shortened it by removing the second query and applying the WHERE clause directly:

```
SELECT a.row, b.row, c.row
FROM 
a LEFT JOIN
b ON (a.id = b.id) LEFT JOIN
c ON (c.otherid= b.otherid)
WHERE b.date NOT BETWEEN '2018-08-04 00:00:00' AND '2018-08-06 23:59:59'
GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY c.otherid DESC;
```

Until here, everything seems fine and both queries return the same result set. The problem is that **the second query takes three times longer to execute than the first one**. How is that possible?
Thanks

Comment: Shortened doesn't always mean optimized.

Comment: How would that first one even run? The syntax is full of errors and there is a missing parentheses.

Comment: have you tried looking at the query plan?  EXPLAIN on both might reveal why.

Comment: @Phiter totally agree!
But in my eyes, removing a whole sub-query by putting a small where clause with a similar filter should be less work for the database, no?

Comment: without knowing the structure or content of the tables, i would guess that the first one is limiting the number of rows to be scanned on table `a`, whereas your version requires scanning every single record.

Comment: @SebastianBreit are you sure you copied those queries to your question properly? You cannot LEFT JOIN WHERE; and also that first query is at very least (among other less obvious issues) missing a closing parenthesis. _Without correction it will be impossible to give a reliable answer on the differences; but even assuming the obvious corrections, those queries do not answer the same question._

Comment: You have not provided enough information for us to help you. Please [read this note about asking good SQL questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/), and pay attention to the section on query performance.  And, your both your queries say `...ON (c.otherid= b.otherid) LEFT JOIN WHERE b.date NOT...`. **LEFT JOIN WHERE** makes no sense. Please check your queries.  Then please [edit] your question.

Comment: I am sorry for the mistakes on the question... I tried to simplify it by removing the real table and field names, and I maked some typos. It's updated now

Comment: That first query still won't work. I'm not at all convinced that if it's fixed that it would still be 1:1 with the second query's result set. Currently the subquery reads `SELECT DISTINCT b.id bb 
INNER JOIN
c cc ON (bb.a_id = bb.a_id)` I suspect that a `FROM b ` is missing and that your `ON` condition is fat fingered. Although, it's besides the point. Run an explain on both and see what they are ACTUALLY doing under the hood. You can't make any assumptions about the execution plan from just looking at the sql.

Comment: Your queries are completely different and will return completely different resultsets and it is not surprising they have different execution times. E.g.: try your query with an empty table "b", the first query will return every row in a, the second query will return no row.

Comment: You changed a BETWEEN with a narrow date range to a NOT BETWEEN.

The first one limits the rows with an index, the second one uses a table scan.

Comment: In addition to the confusion about the query syntax, it's a problem to answer questions about [tag:query-optimization] without any information about the table definitions or number of rows. I just skip questions that don't include the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <name>` for each table in the query. Don't make us guess at your indexes, data types, or constraints! You are not a newbie user on Stack Overflow, you should know how to ask questions better.

Comment: "You changed a BETWEEN with a narrow date range to a NOT BETWEEN. The first one limits the rows with an index, the second one uses a table scan"  Both `BETWEEN` and `NOT BETWEEN` in MySQL can both use a range index scan if there is a correct index  @TerryCarmen check https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3b14M3Brvb72XgYfQrTSRg/0.. The topicstarter should provide `EXPLAIN query` output for every query involved and `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` output for every table involved in the queries so we can stop geussing

Comment: And, the `GROUP BY` may be inappropriate unless everything in the `SELECT` depends on `a.id`.

Comment: And his may run faster by removing `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries are significantly different.  (We're assuming that the missing `FROM` keyword in the subquery in the first version is a result of putting that into the question, and that the original query doesn't have the same syntax errors. Also, the reference to `b.id` in the `SELECT` list of the subquery is highly suspicious, we suspect that's really meant to be a reference to `bb.id` ... but we're just guessing.)

If the two queries are returning the same exact resultset, that's a circumstance in the data. (We could demonstrate data sets where the results of the two queries would be different.)

"Shortening" a query does not necessarily optimize it.

What really matters (in terms of performance) is the execution plan. That is, what operations are being performed, in what order, and with large tables, which indexes are available and being used.

Without table and index definitions, it's not possible to give a definitive diagnosis.

Suggestion: Use MySQL `EXPLAIN` to view the execution plan of each query.

---

Assuming that the original query has a `WHERE` clause of the form:

```
WHERE a.id NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT bb.id 
                      FROM b bb 
                      JOIN c cc
                        ON bb.a_id = cc.a_id
                     WHERE bb.date BETWEEN '2018-08-04 00:00:00' 
                                       AND '2018-08-06 23:59:59'
                       AND bb.id IS NOT NULL
                  )
```

(assuming that we have a guarantee that a value returned by the subquery will never be NULL...)

That could be re-written as a `NOT EXISTS` correlated subquery to achieve an equivalent result:

```
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                       FROM b bb
                       JOIN c cc
                         ON cc.a_id = bb.a_id
                      WHERE bb.date >= '2018-08-04 00:00:00'
                        AND bb.date <  '2018-08-07 00:00:00'
                        AND bb.id = a.id
                   )
```

or it could be re-written as an anti-join

```
  LEFT 
  JOIN b bb 
    ON bb.id = a.id
   AND bb.date >= '2018-08-04 00:00:00'
   AND bb.date <  '2018-08-07 00:00:00'
  LEFT
  JOIN c cc
    ON cc.a_id = bb.a_id
 WHERE cc.a_id IS NULL
```

With large sets, appropriate indexes would need to be available for optimal performance.

The re-write presented in the question is not guaranteed to return an equivalent result.